# Streamline bash script?

Tags: bash

There has to be a way to stream line those 3 find lines in my crudely constructed script below...

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
#
if [ "find /data -type f -perm 400 -print" ] ; then
    find /data -type f -perm 400 -exec echo Modifying {} \;
    find /data -type f -perm 400 -print | xargs chmod 755
else
    echo 'No files to modify'
fi
```

Comment: Why not just use `find /data -type f -perm 400 -exec chmod -v 755 \{\}`? Oh, you'll be missing the "No files to modify" message in case there's no match, but is that really a problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can change it to the following:

```
found=$(find /data -type f -perm 400 -print -quit)

if [ "$found" ]; then
    find /data -type f -perm 400 -exec echo Modifying {} \; -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
else
    echo 'No files to modify`
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `find /data -type f -perm 400 -print -quit`: As soon as this finds the **very first** file with permission `400` in `/data`, it prints the file name and terminates the find immediately. The print is saved to the variable `found` (So we know whether to output "No files to modify" or not later).
- `-exec echo Modifying {} \; -exec chmod 755 {} \;`: You can execute multiple commands on each result returned by find through this chaining syntax
- Note: apparently `find` returns `0` when nothing is found, so using `$?` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4):

```
while read -d $'\0' file; do
    found=yes
    echo "Modifying $file"
    chmod 755 "$file"
done < <(find /data -type f -perm 400 -print0)
if [ "x$found" != "xyes" ]; then
    echo "No files found to modify"
fi
```

This uses the [process substitution feature in Bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). It's equivalent to

```
find ... | while read ...
```

except in that case, the `while read` is performed in a subshell, so we can't set variables that will be seen in the outer shell. Instead, we can use process substitution. `<(cmd)` runs `cmd` in a subshell, with its standard output redirected into a named pipe. The name of that pipe is substituted into the outer command.

We then use `<` to redirect from this pipe into standard input of the `while read` command, which reads each delimited record in turn, and stores the value in the name specified (`file` in this case). By default, `read` breaks on newlines. For most files, that would be fine; you could do:

```
while read file; do
    ...
done < <(find /data -type f -perm 400)
```

and it would work fine. But it is technically possible to have a newline in a filename, in which case that would break. The `-print0` argument to find, and `-d $'\0'` argument to `read`, causes them each to use a null character as a delimiter, which is not valid in a filename.

Comment: Don't you mean `$'\x00'` instead of `$'0'`?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Oops, that's right, fixed. `$'\0'` is sufficient.